# Authors should not publish

Tags: publish

In my Blog should Authors be not allowed to publish posts but to CREATE posts for revision! Admins should later verify and publish them. How can i do it?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Read this, it might be useful. You can also change the capabilities for each rol. https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Summary_of_Roles

Answer (score 1):

The role you are describing is "Contributor". So the option would be to use this role unless you still want to edit Author capabilities which would be done as follows:

```
    function disable_authors_publish_cap() {
        // Get author role object
        $author = get_role( 'author' );
        // Remove the post publishing capability
        $author->remove_cap( 'publish_posts' );
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'disable_authors_publish_cap' );
```

In addition if you would want the exact same capabilities for both Authors and Contributors, then there are some more capabilities to "remove":

```
    function disable_authors_caps() {
        // Get author role object
        $author = get_role( 'author' );

        // List the author vs contributor capabilities
        $caps = array(
            'edit_published_posts',
            'upload_files',
            'publish_posts',
            'delete_published_posts'
        );

        foreach ( $caps as $cap ) {
            // Remove the capability.
            $author->remove_cap( $cap );
        }
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'disable_authors_caps' );
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Hi, in which file can I change this? Thank you! The problem is, at my Blog I cannot create posts as contributor. Just when "publish" is active at role Contributor this role can see the different Posts. When "publish" is not active, then the role sees NO posts.... :/

Comment: It should go to the theme functions.php file for example. Contributor should be able to only post for a review not publish. Although Contributors can see all the posts, they can't edit e.g see the edit screen.